# Is it possible to undo a build just after ./configure, make and BEFORE sudo make install?

Tags: build, makefile, debian, tar, uninstallation

So I was trying to install Python 3.3 from source (I'm running on Debian Wheezy)...

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget [web address of the tar]
$ tar -xzf [tar file]
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/opt/python-3.3.6 
$ make
```

..when I realised I was in production server. The installation should have been installed in local development.

```
$ make uninstall
  make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
```

It seems 'make uninstall' is not available and I do NOT have **checkinstall** installed.

Is it possible to abort the installation and leave everything as it was before? I mean, after firing 'make' I've only build the software but it hasn't been installed into a specific location (i.e. 'sudo make install'), right?

**TL;DR**

Is it just matter of deleting the directory created by the tar file (considering sudo make install hasn't been fired)?

Comment: Make only compiles in the local dir (usually). So just delete the dir and you're set.

Comment: I say ususally since it's merely a convention, nothing stops the make target from trying to create other files, but usually it won't.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I'll delete the dir and hope for the best. If you answer below I'll give you the credit.